# Tracking SharePoint Site Hits

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Does anyone have any experience in tracking hits to a specific SP site? I'm trying to come up with a workflow to do just that, but can't seem to wrap my head around it.  For example - Every time someone (anyone) accesses the site's home page, a number variable in a list goes up by one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Azure Application Insights or Google Analytics. You just need to put some tracking code in your masterpage or if using Modern SharePoint sites in SPO, a [SharePoint Framework Application Customizer](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/08/SPFx-App-Insights.html).